# Javascript Object Method to Set Events

Tags: javascript

I am having a little trouble getting events to be accessible within my handler function... Is there any obvious reason or solution to why my event object is undefined in my handler functions? My structure is similar to the following:

```
var example = {
    'attachEvent': function ( object, event, handler )  {
            if (window.attachEvent) {
                    object.attachEvent( 'on'+event, function() {
                    handler(event);
                }, false );
            } else {
                object.addEventListener( event, function() {
                handler(event);
                }, false );
            }
        },
        'detachEvent': function( object, event, handler ){
            if (window.detachEvent) {
                object.detachEvent( 'on'+event, function(){
                    handler(event);
                }, false ) ;
            } else {
                    object.removeEventListener( event, function() {
                        handler(event);
                    }, false );
            }
        },
        'exampleA' : function(event) {
            console.log('example A executed ' + event.type);
        },
        'exampleB' : function(event) {
            console.log('example B executed');
        }
}

example.attachEvent(window, 'load', function(event) { 
example.exampleA(event);
});
```

Comment: what mccainz pointed out worked, I had forgotten to pass the event into the handler. Does anyone see a reason why my detach event function wouldn't work? thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You aren't passing in the event to your handler, change as below

```
if (window.attachEvent) {
        object.attachEvent( 'on'+event, function(e) {
        handler(e);
    }, false );
} 
else {
    object.addEventListener( event, function(e) {
    handler(e);
    }, false );
}
```

Comment: If memory serves me, the attachEvent (in other words internet exploder) versions wont get an event object as an argument, in that case, you would call the handler with `handler(window.event);` to simulate the proper way of event handling :p

Comment: what mccainz pointed out worked, I had forgotten to pass the event into the handler.  Does anyone see a reason why my detach event function wouldn't work? thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `apply` :

```js
var example = {
    'attachEvent': function ( object, event, handler )  {
            if (window.attachEvent) {
                    object.attachEvent( 'on'+event, function() {
                    handler.apply(object, arguments);
                }, false );
            } else {
                object.addEventListener( event, function() {
                handler.apply(object, arguments);
                }, false );
            }
        },
        'detachEvent': function( object, event, handler ){
            if (window.detachEvent) {
                object.detachEvent( 'on'+event, function(){
                    handler.apply(object, arguments);
                }, false ) ;
            } else {
                    object.removeEventListener( event, function() {
                        handler.apply(object, arguments);
                    }, false );
            }
        },
        'exampleA' : function(event) {
            alert('example A executed ' + event.type);
        },
        'exampleB' : function(event) {
            alert('example B executed');
        }
}

example.attachEvent(window, 'load', function(event) { 
  example.exampleA(event);
});
```